# If we have that $X < \infty$, why doesn't it imply $X$ is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

Suppose that $X$ is some sequence or random variable, etc. I am trying to understand why if $X < \infty$, then that doesn't necessarily mean it has a bound, i.e., there doesn't exist some value $M$ whereby $X \leq M$ for all possible realizations of $X$. Does anyone have an intuition why? Thanks

Comment: When we write  $X < \infty$, I think that is standard notation for $X$ is bounded. I have not written the notation any where else.

Comment: Normally $X < \infty$ means it is bounded. Maybe in some cases you want a sequence which may also has as element $\infty$. In this case you might say $X < \infty$ as the elements are all finite. E.g. the sequence $(1,2,3,4,5,\dots)$ would fullfill this but is obviously not bounded. But as actoh mentioned normally $X < \infty$ means bounded and that above might be something depending on the notion of your source.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг No, see the answers on this question and have a look at the [definition of a random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) $X:\Omega\to E$. Normally $E=\mathbb R$ and in that case we can say $X<\infty$ in the sense that no $\omega\in\Omega$ exists with $X(\omega)=\infty$ wich would be possible if e.g. $E=(-\infty,\infty]$.

Comment: You need to define the notation "$X < \infty$" or this question is meaningless. You can't speak of "intuition" if you don't even know what you're talking about.

Comment: @drhab  I'm sorry I  was speaking from an analyst's point of view. When we say things  are bounded, we use this notation. I did not see the tag random variable, so I assumed the notation was the same.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Okay, but stop feeling sorry now :). If you don't then I will start feeling sorry.

Comment: @drhab Sure, I'm fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $X$ successively takes the values $1,2,3, ...$. Then $X$ is unbounded, even though each value it takes is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is not a special ad-hoc notaion, but that it means "$X(\omega)<\infty$ for all $\omega$":

For instance $X:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $X(\omega)=\omega$.